# DBT - dbt test --store-failures only if test case has failed

Tags: dbt

I added the below code to dbt_project.yml.

```
tests:
  +store_failures: true
```

Is there any way to store only the failed tests in the table

Comment: This feature already does that (only stores the results of the failed tests in a table). What are you trying to do? What isn't working as expected? See the [docs](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/store_failures)

Comment: dbt creates empty tables for passing tests as well, Can we change this default behavior

Comment: I think that is unavoidable -- dbt first inserts the results from the test query into that table, then counts the records in that table to determine whether or not there are failures.  See [here](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/tests#storing-test-failures) for more info